# Relative section specification

Tags: latex

Is it possible to specify the \section \subsection \subsubsection etc. level relative to the previous level?  What I'm thinking of is something like

```
\thissection The top level  
   \pushsection  
   \thissection The next level down  
   \thissection One more  
      \pushsection   
      \thissection Deeper  
   \popsection  
   \thissection At the same level and follows "one more"
```

etc.  The idea is that I'm writing a document from the inside
out, i.e., starting at a deeper levels, and I don't know how many layers will be on top of it.  This will avoid the need to do a massive re-leveling by renaming \subsection to \subsubsection etc.

BTW, a Google search for latex and "relative section" results in hits that almost exclusively involve misuse of the word "relative"; the authors meant to say "relevant section".

Thank you for any ideas.

Liam

Comment: Well the "Code and Preformatted Text" section advice in editing-help didn't work, I meant the example to be in a <pre><code> block with indents.  Sorry.

Comment: It sounds like, instead of trying to write all this code, that you should make an outline, and the use a top-down approach, rather than inside-out. I've written many documents using the inside-out things, and they always need much more editing & re-structuring than one written with a top-down approach & an outline. I know this doesn't answer your question directly, but there is a lot to be said for a more structured approach to document construction.

Comment: Mica: I understand what you're saying, but the problem is a little more complicated than I stated.  I am writing a talk using beamer and I've already written the paper, so I have an outline.  I know I have more material than I can fit into a twenty minute talk, but I don't know how much I can fit.  If I can fit two top-level topics, those will be the "sections" and everything under them the "subsections" etc.  If I can only fit one top-level topic, than that's the whole subject of the talk, and the parts of that are the sections.

Comment: ahhhhh. I see. God speed, then. :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could implement your `\pushsection`, `\popsection`, and `\thissection` using a counter and if-then-else logic:

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{section-level}
\setcounter{section-level}{0}
\newcommand{\pushsection}{\addtocounter{section-level}{1}}
\newcommand{\popsection}{\addtocounter{section-level}{-1}}
\newcommand{\thissection}[1]
{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{section-level}}{0}}{\section{#1}}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{section-level}}{1}}{\subsection{#1}}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{section-level}}{2}}{\subsubsection{#1}}{}
}
```

This will work exactly as you show above, for 3 levels of section. Of course, you should probably do something to handle out-of-range nesting levels (such as crashing the TeX build and printing a warning).

Comment: Indeed it does.  I added  

      \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{section-level}}{3}}{\paragraph{#1}}{}  
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{section-level}}  {4}}{\subparagraph{#1}}{}  

I doubt I'll get that deep, but it's nice to have it there.
AUCTeX unfortunately no longer puts the section title in a big font, 
but I can live with that.

Thanks.

Liam

Answer (score 7):

I've made a package out of the suggestions in the other answers.

Instead of the stack metaphor, the commands are `\leveldown`, `\levelup` and `\dynsection`.

The `asection` environment is present and I added a `\gotochapterlevel`.

`\leveldown` and `\levelup` take optional arguments to jump multiple levels at once.

I tried to respect the minimum and maximum levels of different document classes and their names but that's a mess, really. So for now you better just hack your favorite sectioning hierarchy into the thing which should be easy.

I hope someone will find this useful or can even improve on it (shouldn't be that hard, really):

[Relative Sectioning Package](https://github.com/mudd1/relsec)

Comment: I think you should put this on github or something like that.

Comment: @exic Thanks for the suggestion :) https://github.com/mudd1/relsec I should probably also put this on CTAN but that was enough submitting for one day and I'm a bit afraid of being crucified to be honest.

Comment: Adding `let b:match_words .= ',\\\<leveldown\>:\\\<levelup\>'` to `.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim` makes it even nicer if you use the matchit.vim plugin.

Comment: @exic I'm not using vim myself but I can add this to the readme and link back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Given the following recursive macro to generate a string a number of times:

```
\newcommand{\Repeat}[2]{% #1=number of times, #2=what to repeat
  \ifnum\the\numexpr#1\relax>0%
    #2%
    \expandafter\Repeat\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1-1\relax}{#2}%
  \fi%
}%
```

and a global counter that will say how many "sub"s we need to prepend:

```
\newcounter{section-level}
\setcounter{section-level}{0}
```

then you have the macros:

```
\def\pushsection{\addtocounter{section-level}{1}}
\def\popsection{\addtocounter{section-level}{-1}}

\def\thissection#1{%
    \csname\Repeat{\value{section-level}}{sub}section\endcsname%
}%
```

However, I would also have considered defining an environment which does the pushing and popping:

```
\newenvironment{asection}[2][\defopt]{% #1=toc entry (optional), #2=heading
  \def\defopt{#2}%
  \thissection[#1]{#2}%
  \pushsection%
}{%
  \popsection%
}%
```

and rewrite your example into:

```
\begin{asection}{The top level}
  \begin{asection}{The next level down}\end{asection}
  \begin{asection}{One more}
    \begin{asection}{Deeper}\end{asection}
  \end{asection}
  \begin{asection}{At the same level and follows "one more"}\end{asection}
\end{asection}
```

Comment: Though the TeX programming is interesting, for me (in beamer) this is probably too general.  I ended up not using the deeper level sectioning, because beamer doesn't really look good with more than a couple levels.  I don't like the environment style for sections because my sections are very lengthy and finding the matching close for the open (or vice versa) is hard.